# Vim: Pyflakes Conflicting With Vimgrep/Grep

Tags: vim, pyflakes

I just recently installed Pyflakes Vim plugin. It works very fine and is very helpful. Unfortunately it uses the error list in case there is an error. So if I make a search-in-files using Vimgrep or Grep, then after using :cnext to show the next error, the error list will most probably be replaced with the list of errors generated by Pyflakes automatically.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:lvimgrep` (abbreviated `:lv`) to use the location list instead of the quickfix list. Both work the same way, but the `c*` commands are replaced with `l*`. See `:help quickfix.txt` for more details

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the location list variant. I'll definitely be adding that one to my tool belt.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the accepted answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814534/how-to-make-vim-error-list-permanent-using-pyflakes) PyFlakes has an option to disable its use of the quickfix list.

```
let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 0
```

You can either have this in your vimrc to always have it off, or you can turn it on and off by using the let statement as an ex command.

To turn on PyFlakes' use of the quickfix list again do:

```
let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 1
```