# How to make Vim error list permanent using PyFlakes?

Tags: python, vim, pep8, pyflakes

I want to use pep8 as my makeprg in order to check and fix my code compliance to [PEP8 (Style guide for python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/http://).

I used the command `:set makeprg=pep8\ --repeat\ %`, and when I do `:make` it works, the error list is populated and I can use `:cn`, `:cp` and `:copen` to navigate and see the error list in the QuickFix window.

But as soon as I change something in my python source file the errorlist becomes empty, the QuickFix window loses its content and I cannot navigate the list anymore.

I suspect that this is caused by PyFlakes, a Vim extension that highlights Python errors on-the-fly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Checking for "code compliance" against a style *guide* is exactly how a style guide should not be used.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard then what do you think the pep8 utility is for? I use it to check if I forgot to adopt some guideline and to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyflakes has an option that should solve your problem, just put this in your ~/.vimrc :

`let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 0`

This actually stops pyflakes from using (and breaking) the quickfix window, that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

See [this vim extension](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2914)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This extension does not fix the problem, but it helped me in identifying the root cause. It seems like pyflakes uses too the quickfix window, and with this plugin I see it overwriting the content, while without the plugin the QuickFix window just became empty.